# Why doesn't copying a jTextField work?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

What I'm trying to do is program a method to create a jTextField from a "default" field, then move it. Essentially it's one of those "Click to add row" deals.

Here's some of what I've got so far.

```
public javax.swing.JTextField[] jTextFieldArr = new javax.swing.JTextField[2];

jTextFieldArr[0] = jTextField1;
jTextFieldArr[0].setLocation(6, 74);
```

Setting the location of jTextFieldArr[0] ALSO changes the location of jTextField1, why?

Comment: `jTextFieldArr[0]` is a reference for `jTextField1`, i.e. theyre the same component

Comment: @Reimeus I'm still not quite sure I understand why though. When declaring jTextFieldArr, I made no mention of jTextField1. I'm sure there's a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I can't seem to search Google correctly about this issue.

Comment: @lzodn What Reimeus is saying is that when you do `jTextFieldArr[0] = jTextField1`, you don't create a new component with its fields holding the same values as the ones in `jTextField1`.

Comment: As Reimeus has already stated, `jTextFieldArr[0] == jTextField1 = true`. Assigning `jTextField` to `jTextFieldArr[0]` doesn't make a copy of anything, it just assigns the memory reference of `jTextField1 ` to `jTextFieldArr[0]`